# Passing input.data to shell script and comparing to correct_output.data in OSX

Tags: c, macos, shell, terminal

There are three parts to this. The objective is to pass an input file to a C-Program, have it run through the input, create an output and compare that to the correct_output.data.

Here is the Shell I was given:

```
#!/bin/sh
input_file="input.data"
output_file="output.data"
correct_output_file="output_correct.data"
while read line do  echo $line | ./Prak1A3 done < $input_file > output.tmp
sed -i 's/Geben Sie einen Satz ein: Eingegeben: //g' output.tmp cat     output.tmp > $output_file
rm output.tmp
diff -u -s $output_file $correct_output_file
```

Here is the C-Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
//char * input="this is a test sentence";
//int index;
int charCount;
int wordCount;
char currentChar;
int isInWord=0;



charCount = 0;
wordCount = 1;

currentChar = getchar();

while(currentChar != '\n'){

    if(getchar() == ' ' || getchar() == '\t'){
        isInWord = 0;

    }else if( getchar()!='\t'||getchar()!=' '){
        charCount++;
        if(isInWord == 0){
            wordCount++;
            isInWord=1;
        }
    }
currentChar = getchar();

printf("%d Wörter, %d Zeichen  \n", wordCount, charCount);
}
}
```

The Input File:

```
Ein normaler Satz. 
Ein Satz mit    vielen  Leerzeichen. 
Tabs    und   
Leerzeichen kombiniert. Ein Tab      nach dem Satz.     
      Leerer  Start.    Tabs vorne und hinten.
```

Correct Output File

```
3 Wörter, 16 Zeichen 
5 Wörter, 28 Zeichen 
4 Wörter, 29 Zeichen 
5 Wörter, 18 Zeichen
0 Wörter, 0 Zeichen 
2 Wörter, 12 Zeichen 
4 Wörter, 19 Zeichen
```

Right now I am creating an executable in terminal with `gcc -o prak Prak1A3.c` However, I am not seeing any use of the shell-script and if I run the exectuable it launches another terminal window and waits for input from my keyboard. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Loosk like you are supposed to run the shell script which will run your program. The script expects your program binary to be `Prak1A3` so you need to compile it with `gcc -o Prak1A3 Prak1A3.c`

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've just done it as you had suggested. The shell runs and mostly works but I do get an error at line 21.

I compiled with    gcc -o counter Prak1A3.c and tired two things in the shell file. [Line 21: echo $line | ./counter ]. This leaves the terminal in an endless input-loop. If [Line 21: echo $line | counter ] gives me 7 iterations of [test.sh: line 21: counter: command not found] back. Any last help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you forget the script and the output file for now. Just run your program directly on the command line and debug it until it produces the right output. Run it like this: `./counter < input.data`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Much better :)

It appears to be working now. Innitially the printf was inside the while-loop but I moved that outside, however, the files still aren't matching. Currently it's "-5 Wörter, 21 Zeichen" for every line. Also, which tags are you using to display your code in grey in the comments? I can't find it in the help-file

Comment: Well you haven't really told us what the program is supposed to do. All you said is that it needs to "run through the input". But you haven't stated what processing it is meant to do.

Comment: My Bad. It basically takes sentences and counts the characters and words (regardless if there are two spaceses or tabs) and prints the results out. I.e. If I feed it "this    sentence is   a test" it will print "5 words, 19 Characters" (in german).

Comment: Suggest you ask a new question. Your code has some fundamental issues with it. Including but not limited to: 1. `while(currentChar != '\n')` will stop when it sees a newline which means it can stop after the first input line. Should check for `EOF` instead 2. You have too many `getchar` calls. You should have only one call and then all your checks should use the value returned from that one call. As it is now, your code is almost always a infinete loop because `while(currentChar != '\n')` is almost never true because the other `getchar` calls are likely to swallow the newline character.

Comment: "which tags are you using to display your code in grey in the comments". Enclose the text with backticks. That is \`grey text\`.